# How to change the style of only the last Column in a Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I have a React component that maps an array to react-bootstrap Columns in a row like so

```
<Container fluid>
  <Row xs={1} md={props.title === 'big rules' ? 1 : 2} lg={props.title === 'big rules' ? 2 : 4}>
    {props.rules.map((rule, index) => (
      <Col key={index}>
        {rule}
      </Col>
    ))}
  </Row>
</Container>
```

and I have a .sass file which gives each column a border on the right hand side,

```
.col {
 padding: 1rem;
 border-style: groove;
 border-top: none;
 border-bottom: none;
 border-left: none;
}
```

How do I setup my css so that the final column in each row is ignored, given that the number of columns changes based on the size of the screen?

Edit: Adding some images to hopefully better explain the issue
[image: Row with 3 columns, last column has no border as expected]

This row works as expected because there are only 3 items mapped into columns.

[image: Row with 12 items mapped in, only last entry has no border]

This row has 12 entries added to it, and the last column up until the final entry has a border.

Comment: so now I can see these 12 elements are in the same Row that's why the problem exists.

Comment: @SebMaz93 yes, do you know of a way to solve this?

Comment: I tried a lot like with `getboundingclientrect` and other things but there is no easy solution for what you are asking if the elements are dynamic, you have to change your structure.

Comment: @SebMaz93 so how would you suggest laying things out to keep my functionality similar

Answer (score 0):

here is the working example:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="containere">
      <div className="row">
        {[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].map((rule, index) => (
          <div className="col" key={index}>
            {rule}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div className="row">
        {[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].map((rule, index) => (
          <div className="col" key={index}>
            {rule}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div className="row">
        {[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1].map((rule, index) => (
          <div className="col" key={index}>
            {rule}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

scss:

```
.container {
 
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-style: groove;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  &:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }
}
```

just added &:last-child {} selector on that .col class

Comment: I attempted this previously but it only removes the border from the last item in the grid, so it works if the grid is only 1 row but for more rows the final column has a border still

Comment: @DanielCollins it should work since we are selecting each last-child inside row and not only one row, if you can share larger code that can help more, seems the problem is somewhere else

Comment: @DanielCollins I've updated the code on my example check its working doesn't matter how many rows we have. maybe it is not working because of a stronger selector being used from Bootstrap side, try using !important or more specific selectors

Comment: In your example, the code is just repeated, my issue is that the array I provide to be mapped is sometimes larger than the specified number of columns for the row, so it looks like a new row has been created in the UI but in fact there is no second row component in the code, if that makes sense. I have added images to my initial question to hopefully provide some clarity